# How can I programatically download the output of Get-HistoricalSearch?

Tags: windows, powershell, exchange

I have to use Powershell to perform some message tracing. This involves using Start-HistoricalSearch to begin a search, followed by Get-HistoricalSearch to get the results once it's done. Get-HistoricalSearch returns data along these lines:

```
PS C:\Users\dscally> Get-HistoricalSearch -JobId "e4e8cecd-e943-4d61-b588-6a0a3c8d3cba" | select *


RunspaceId              : 9b3d4d8f-c257-477e-b4e9-8379c2bf788f
JobId                   : e4e8cecd-e943-4d61-b588-6a0a3c8d3cba
Identity                : e4e8cecd-e943-4d61-b588-6a0a3c8d3cba
SubmitDate              : 09/06/2020 13:25:40
ReportTitle             : First 50 People -90 Days Received
Status                  : Done
Rows                    : 171069
FileRows                : 50000
ErrorCode               :
ErrorDescription        :
FileUrl                 : < report URL here> 
ReportStatusDescription : Complete – Ready for download
ReportType              : MessageTrace
NotifyAddress           : {< my email address here >}
StartDate               : 11/03/2020 14:25:40
EndDate                 : 09/06/2020 14:25:40
DeliveryStatus          : All
SenderAddress           : {}
RecipientAddress        : {<addresses go here>...}
OriginalClientIP        :
MessageID               : {}
DLPPolicy               : {}
TransportRule           : {}
Locale                  : en-GB
Direction               : All
CompletionDate          : 09/06/2020 13:47:10
EstimatedCompletionTime :
JobProgress             :
EncryptionType          :
EncryptionTemplate      :
IsSaved                 : False
NumOfBlocks             : 0
CompressFile            : False
NetworkMessageID        : {}
Url                     :
```

I need to ideally programatically fetch the report linked to by the FileURL property. Unfortunately it's behind a Microsoft SSO authentication page, and I'm struggling to do it other than through the GUI. Is there a way to pass the authentication it needs through Invoke-WebRequest or some other cmdlet so that I can download the reports with a script.

The context is, there's like several hundred of these and that's more manual clicking than I really want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to download the log with Edge:

```
$logg = Get-HistoricalSearch -JobId xxxxxx... | select FileUrl

& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe' $logg.FileUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you see the value of the **FileUrl** parameter if you download the report via EAC(**mail flow** -> **message trace** -> **View pending or completed traces** -> **Download this report**) or export the report to a CSV via the command "**Get-HistoricalSearch -JobId** "<**Search JobId>" | select * | Export-Csv <.CSV File Path>\Report.csv**"?
[image]

Comment: Downloading through the GUI is what I'm trying to avoid, and the Export-CSV option will just save the output from Get-HistoricalSearch (which just has the URL to the data, and not the data itself). I need to access the URL shown in the FileURL property of the Get-HistoricalSearch output

Comment: @DanScally Hi, based on my knowledge and the test result, if we request a historical search, we still need visit the URL to download/access the report. To get accurate help of the historical search problem, you could mark your case with more tags(e.g. office365).

Comment: @Ivan -- there are web request powershell cmdlets.  Dan was explicitly asking for a powershell solution and not a GUI solution.

Comment: Is there any update on how to get the .CSV file result rather than getting it via email ?